# Problems with installation of Google App Engine SDK for php in OS X

Tags: php, macos, google-app-engine

I'm trying to create Google App Engine environment in my Mac OS X Mountain Lion.
Downloaded the Googleapplauncher.dmg file.
While I tried to unzip the file it shows "the following disk images couldn't be opened" .
Reason: "Not recognised".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the download  was corrupted if you are getting an error with the disk image.  Go back to the downloads page at https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads and look at the SHA1 checksum.  Then, go to your Terminal app on your mac and run the following:

```
openssl sha1 [put the full path to the file here without brackets]
```

For example:

```
openssl sha1 /Users/me/Desktop/myFile.dmg
```

If you get a different value than the one on the Downloads page, you know your file is not properly downloaded and you should try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I don't see any sha1 checksum for php SDK. All there are are for python, java and go. I'm re-downlaoding it. Thanks again. It helps me a lot so far.